# Pytesseract not giving excpected resaults

Tags: image-processing, python-tesseract, image-recognition

using pytesseract for image to text along with some basic image enhancing, Problem is that im getting very weird resaults.
Pyton

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageEnhance

filename = 'image3.png'
color_image = Image.open(filename)

# Enhance Color Level

curr_col = ImageEnhance.Color(color_image)
new_col = 5
img_colored = curr_col.enhance(new_col)
\#enhance sharpness
curr_col = ImageEnhance.Sharpness(color_image)
new_enh = 2
img_colored = curr_col.enhance(new_enh)

# Color level enhanced by a factor of 2.5

bw = img_colored.convert('L')
bw.save('BW_image.png')
img_colored.save('enchanc.png')

img1 = np.array(Image.open("BW_image.png"))
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img1)

print(text)
```

This is image3.png and this is what i get printed in the console
"Nam 65 can gala"
[image3.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jU7Fv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, you apply some enhancements on the image 'image3.png', but you open another image img1 and then pass it to pytesseract.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageEnhance

filename = 'image3.png'
color_image = Image.open(filename)

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(color_image)

print(text)
```

this code outputs: Profit: 68.0666 gold

Comment: Hi, When i run this I get
'
Mum.“
'
Could it have something to do with me running this in replit? I dont see why, but thats the only thing i can think off.